# how to transform image from gallery or camera into base64?

Tags: react-native

I have a function that takes the image from the gallery or camera and sends it to an area where the user can view it.

```
    import React, {useState} from 'react';
    import {View, TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet, Image} from 'react-native';
    
    import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
    
    export default function Upload() {
      const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState();
    
      function imagePickerCallback(data) {
        if (data.didCancel) {
          return;
        }
    
        if (data.error) {
          return;
        }
    
        if (data.customButton) {
          return;
        }
    
        if (!data.assets[0].uri) {
          return;
        }
    
        setAvatar(data.assets[0]);
      }
    
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Image
            source={{
              uri: avatar
                ? avatar.uri
                : 'https://mltmpgeox6sf.i.optimole.com/w:761/h:720/q:auto/https://redbanksmilesnj.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/man-avatar-placeholder.png',
            }}
            style={styles.avatar}
          />
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() =>
              ImagePicker.launchCamera(imagePickerCallback)
            }>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>camera</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
    
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() =>
              ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(imagePickerCallback)
            }>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>galery</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
    
        </View>
      );
    }
```

I'm filling the image source with the URI. I would like to know how to take this image and make it base64 to send it to firebase storage.
If I need to install a library, tell me which one to install.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the library definition for options which is the first parameter.  You can tell the library to return the base64 string. options: { includeBase64: true }

https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker#options

And that will return the below object with base64
https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker#asset-object

See below example:

```js
    import React, {useState} from 'react';
    import {View, TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet, Image} from 'react-native';
    
    import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
    
    export default function Upload() {
      const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState();
    
      function imagePickerCallback(data) {
        if (data.didCancel) {
          return;
        }
    
        if (data.error) {
          return;
        }
    
        if (data.customButton) {
          return;
        }
    
        if (!data.assets[0].uri) {
          return;
        }
        
        if((data.assets?.length ?? 0) > 0 && data.assets[0].base64){
          //Here is my base64 string of assets[0]
        }
    
        setAvatar(data.assets[0]);
      }
      
      const options = {
       includeBase64: true
      }
    
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Image
            source={{
              uri: avatar
                ? avatar.uri
                : 'https://mltmpgeox6sf.i.optimole.com/w:761/h:720/q:auto/https://redbanksmilesnj.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/man-avatar-placeholder.png',
            }}
            style={styles.avatar}
          />
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() =>
              ImagePicker.launchCamera(options, imagePickerCallback)
            }>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>camera</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
    
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() =>
              ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, imagePickerCallback)
            }>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>galery</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
    
        </View>
      );
    }
```